# Why thread keeps hanging during condition_variable.wait()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

I'm trying to write a program, that uses threads. The thread should sleep and wait until head pointer of Stack changes, then do some stuff and sleep again. However, my thread keeps hanging on wait function, and my program hangs with it, waiting for statement to change. But it won't, because whole program waiting to thread complete. So.. Here is my code, it's working, when I put the thread join into destructor, but I want it to run before the pushes happening, so it can notice changes during run, and then when int main() completed, safely terminated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

class Stack {
private:
    Node* head;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread writeThread;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    Node* prevHead;
    std::condition_variable cv;

public:

    Stack() {
        head = nullptr;
        prevHead = nullptr;
        outFile.open("C:\\Users\\mayday\\Desktop\\stack.txt");
        writeThread = std::thread(&Stack::WriteStack, this);
    }


    ~Stack() {
        writeThread.join();
    }

    void Push(int data) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    void WriteStack() {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            cv.wait(lock, [this]() { return head != prevHead; });
            Node* temp = head;
            while (temp != nullptr) {
                outFile << temp->data << " ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            outFile << std::endl;
            outFile.close();
            prevHead = head;
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

};

int main() {
    Stack s;
    s.Push(1);
    s.Push(2);
    s.Push(3);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried creating new void method for thread join() to execute it from main, but if I implement it before Push(), then it will sleep forever and do nothing. Even with calls from destructor, it's just doing stuff and keeps freezing waiting on condition changes. Of course I can provide it a way out by checking head == prevHead in the end, and then breaking it, but I want it just to sleep in background, until it will be notified for changes. How can I overcome this freeze?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: WriteStack locks mtx and prevents Push from locking that same mtx

Comment: This may not be your bug, but you do not need to explicitly invoke lock.unlock. The destructor of std::unique_ptr will do that for you.

Comment: `std::lock_guard()` would be better, wouldn't it?

Comment: @sweenish - unique_lock is required for condition variables.

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

As I called out the comments, there's no reason to explicitly invoke `lock.unlock()` since the destructor of unique_lock will do that for you.

Also, I tend to favor `notify_all()` instead of `notify_one()` just so I don't have to think about what additional edge cases that might create.

But neither of the above issues are the reason for your hang.

Your code is hanging because there's nothing to signal to the thread to exit.  Your main thread just hangs on a call to `writeThread.join()` in the Stack destructor waiting for the worker thread to exit.  And your worker thread is just hanging out waiting to be notified again.

Add a new bool member to your class called `needToExit` initialized to `false` in the constructor.

In the destructor, set this variable to true (while under a mutex lock) and then signal the cv.

In your thread, check this variable as an exit condition.

**Update**. Based on your comments, I also added a change to `Push` such that it will wait for the worker thread to finish processing a previous head pointer change. A `cv.notify_all` call is made from the thread when to signal back to the main thread each time it finishes processing a head change.

```
class Stack {
private:
    Node* head;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread writeThread;
    std::ofstream outFile;
    Node* prevHead;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool needToExit;   // DECLARE THIS

public:

    Stack() {
        head = nullptr;
        prevHead = nullptr;

        needToExit = false;   // INIT TO FALSE

        outFile.open("C:\\Users\\jselbie\\Desktop\\stack.txt");
        writeThread = std::thread(&Stack::WriteStack, this);
    }


    ~Stack() {

        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            needToExit = true;  // SET UNDER LOCK IN DESTRUCTOR
        }
        cv.notify_all(); // signal cv to wake up thread to check condition

        writeThread.join();
    }


    void Push(int data) {
        std::cout << "push(" << data << ")\n";

        // wait for any previous head change to
        // be picked up and processed by the thread
        cv.wait(lock, [this]() { 
            return (head == prevHead)
        });

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = data;
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
        cv.notify_all();
    }

    void WriteStack() {
        while (true) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
            cv.wait(lock, [this]() { 
                // CHECK needToExit in addition to pointer change
                return ((head != prevHead) || needToExit); 
            });

            if (head != prevHead) {
                Node* temp = head;
                while (temp != nullptr) {
                    outFile << temp->data << " ";
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                outFile << std::endl;
                outFile.close();
                prevHead = head;

                cv.notify_all(); // notify main thread
            }

            if (needToExit)
                break; // EXIT THREAD WHEN needtoExit==true
            }
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and edits, but just like that, seems like there is no point in notifying the thread within Push() method, there are no threads exists waiting for signal. I want my thread to start at the begin of the program, and wait for Push() happens, that's why I implemented this notify. And that's why this stuck on wait() function bothered me. How can I make it sleep in the begin of the program, so Push() can do some stuff and then be notified from it?

Comment: That's exactly what my changes accomplish. What are you confused on?

Comment: Look at my main() thread in the question. Destructor is called when the function exits. So the thread is joining at the very end, when all the pushes already done. I want it to join at the start, so when main thread do push(), it can detect the changes and pass the cv.wait. As I said in the question, I tried do writeThread.join() at start, but it stucks on cv.wait and waiting forever.

Comment: You want the worker thread to wake up on the first Push or every Push?  If the second Push is invoked before the thread has finished processing the change induced by the first thread, do you want to block the main thread until the worker thread has a chance to keep up?

Comment: I need it to wake up after *head changes. And yes, I need to block the main thread, before worker done with writing job. In more advanced setup, I think I better create a buffer that will store all the changes we have to make. But for now, I just don't know how to suspend the writeThread, so main thread can continue to run. If I write a function for joining the writeThread, and call it before pushes will happen, it will hang on cv.wait, waiting for changes, that will never happen, cause the main thread waiting for writeThread to finish.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  All you need is to have the main thread "wait" for the worker thread to pick up the previous change and reset `prevHead=head`. You simply re-use the condition variable you already have and add an additional notify_all and wait call.  See the update I made above.

Comment: Okay, I finally realized, that I didn't understand how the threads works. The thing is, when I initialize one in constructor, it will soon or later be launched after member initialized, without even a join method. So your suggest to use lock in push() actually does what I wanted. It blocks main thread, and then working thread finally wakes up to do the job. I just placed unique_lock in Push() at the end of the function, so the push can do what it need to do first, and moved outFile.open from contructor to WriteStack(), because outFile.close() closed the file after the first push. Much Thanks!

Comment: Also, i didn't realize, that OS need some time to allocate the resources for new thread. So that's why my main() managed to finish before the thread even started. :)